# SimpleXML (Zend_Config_Xml actually) and foreach : which tag am I iterating?

Tags: simplexml, zend-config, zend-config-xml

I'm implementing a little event manager in order to use the Observer pattern. To subscribe my observers to my events, I'm using the following xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configData>
    <subscriptions>
        <subscription>
            <eventName>event_name</eventName>
            <class>My_Observer_Class</class>
            <function>myFunction</function>
        </subscription>
        <subscription>
            <eventName>other_event_name</eventName>
            <class>My_Observer_Otherclass</class>
            <function>myOtherFunction</function>
        </subscription>
    </subscriptions>
</configData>
```

I'm using a `foreach` to loop on the subscriptions :

```
foreach($subscriptions->subscription as $subscription) {
    /* using $subscription->eventName etc... */
}
```

And everything is ok, each `$subscription` item has it's `eventName` etc...

But here comes my problem :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configData>
    <subscriptions>
        <subscription>
            <eventName>event_name</eventName>
            <class>My_Observer_Class</class>
            <function>myFunction</function>
        </subscription>
    </subscriptions>
</configData>
```

Here I have only **one** `<subscription>` node. And my `foreach` loops on the `subscription` **children** !
To solve this problem, I'd like to know how I can check if the xml file contains several `<subscription>` tags, or just one...

Any help will be appreciated :)

**Edit :** Is there a way to use `xpath` with my `Zend_Config_Xml object` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, this is an issue with Zend_Config_XML which is not present in PHP's native SimpleXML.

Given your second example as `$xml`, I can run the following and get the word 'subscription' as expected:

```
 $configData = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 foreach($configData->subscriptions->subscription as $subscription)
 {
     echo $subscription->getName(); 
 }
```

Comment: Actually this is what I did. I didn't use xpath. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Please try below code, i have tested it with both of sample  XML's you provided.

```
<?php

$subscriptions = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$scTag = $subscriptions->xpath("//subscription");

 foreach($scTag as $subscription) {
     echo $subscription->eventName;
          /* using $subscription->eventName etc... */
 } 
?>
```

hope this help !

Comment: Actually, I'm using Zend_Config_Xml to load this config : `$managerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH .'/configs/eventManager.xml') ;`... This class has no native `xpath` function :(

Comment: Check this may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576995/iterating-zend-config-xml-with-only-1-child-node & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415651/zend-config-xml-strange-behaviour I think you can Use SimpleXML instead of Zend_Config_Xml

Comment: Yes I finally changed `Zend_Config_Xml` to `SimpleXML` since I had no need for `Zend_Config` functions. Thx.